# Multi-step page interaction and snapshots using Rails and PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, phantomjs, poltergeist

Our Rails app needs to take snapshots of multiple URLs from a given domain. For the moment these will just be simple GET requests but in the future users will be able to input more complex instructions such as clicking on page elements, filling out forms etc. before a snapshot is taken. I've settled on PhantomJS as a backend, but I'm not clear on the best way to interact with it.

PhantomJS's site has excellently clear docs and examples of how to control it using pre-written JS scripts and arguments. This seems to work great if your interactions can all be captured in a rigid script: create the page instance, load a URL, do some things, then call `phantom.exit();`.

But in our case, we want to be able to send a variety of instructions to a *persistent* browser session, in the way Capybara does. For example, a given user-defined script may call for loading a URL, clicking on an element by ID, then rendering a screenshot with a parameter-defined browser width. Then click on a link or load another URL and take more actions, etc. So while our immediate need (load a URL and take a screenshot) can easily be handled as a 10-line JS script, it seems that pretty soon we'll need to be able to send commands more modularly, to a persistent PhantomJS browser open that stays open between commands until we explicitly close it.

Is there a way to "modularize" my communications with PhantomJS? From looking through the [Poltergeist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist) code, I see that they use web sockets to send individual requests to PhantomJS. Do I need to learn how to do that? Should I just use Capybara? Is there some simpler solution that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance. Just trying to figure out how to get started here.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25221906/1816580

Comment: Thanks, that answer helps. Do you have any experience using Capybara for something like this?

Comment: No, I do not. The suggested solution is only viable if you can and want to make everything yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was overthinking this. I've settled on using Capybara and Poltergeist, which takes care of PhantomJS so I don't have to talk with it directly. It turns out Capybara can easily be used outside of your test suite.

Given a Gemfile where `capybara` and `poltergeist` are present (in development and production, not just test environment), and given a certain class where I needed to load pages, interact and take screenshots, the following code loads Capybara and gives me access to the same friendly methods I'm used to in the test suite.

```
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

class Snapshot
  include Capybara::DSL
  Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist

  def initialize(url)
    visit url
    click_link "#signup"
    puts page.html
    # etc.
  end
end
```

Then instantiate this class in the normal way:

```
...
s = Snapshot.new('http://www.google.com')
puts s.page.html
if s.page.status_code == 200
  ...
end
...
```

(I'm using Poltergeist and PhantomJS as opposed to Capybara's default because I need to be able to interact with JS on the page.)